# liferay SSL port redirecting without port number

Tags: ssl, liferay-6

I am facing a problem trying to setup SSL for Liferay which seems straight forward but I am not able to crack it.
I am using Liferay 6.2 with MySQL 5.5 and trying to setup SSL on the server.

As I am experimenting I have followed http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes (other sites too giving similar suggestions)

Now I am able to see the login page with https:liferay001:8443 and when I login the redirected url loses the port number and no page is shown after that(`https://liferay001/web/guest/welcome?p_p_auth=PlbcFdOI&p_p_id=49&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_49_struts_action=%2Fmy_sites%2Fview&_49_groupId=10204&_49_privateLayout=false`)

But if I login via non SSL ie. liferay001:8080 the logged in page come in fine. I checked via developer tool and the 8080 is not losing the port when showing the :8080/web/guest/welcome?

I tried to login via 8080 port and then switch to 8443(SSL) port and the page shows up in SSL without issues.

So any navigation from SSL is making the port to be lost in url.

I have tried this in Windows and Ubuntu and both are showing the same behavior.

Is there changes I have to make on the Liferay side to get this running? I am not able to figure out which file changes I have to do along with server.xml.

Right now I am using .keystore in the server.xml file and not using anything complicated.

---

I have also experimented by adding the following to the portal-ext.properties

```
company.security.auth.requires.https=true
session.enable.phishing.protection=false
web.server.protocol=https
```

This has caused the server to not return any response now ie no login page as response too.

Comment: i found another person having same issue at https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/40759691

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer as there will be folks who will be not able to proceed without this knowledge.

I have tried to engage few folks in my team and all of them came to the same point where they could not proceed.

the answer is to have all the following entries in your portal-ext.properties

```
company.security.auth.requires.https=true
session.enable.phishing.protection=false
web.server.protocol=https
web.server.https.port=8443
```